# How to prevent onInput from firing during dynamic component initialization?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, events

I have a table that has been created dynamically, and am attempting to put full CRUD capabilities onto it. For business reasons I am unable to use external libraries for this, and so have resulted in using basic HTML with react. I am currently trying to detect changes within the data. My problem is in regards to the onInput event with the div inside the  tag. When the components are first initialized with the data, the onInput event fires for each one rather than waiting for an actual user input. To a degree I understand why this is happening, but I am in need of a workaround for it or an alternative. I have created a small demo below to show a mock of the current code:

Parent class:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class FormContainer extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            rowData : myData
        }
        this.onInput = this.onInput.bind(this)
    }

    onInput = (rowKey) => {
        console.log(rowKey)
    }

    render() {
        return(
           <Grid 
           data={this.state.rowData}
           onInput={this.onInput}
           />
        )
    }
}
```

Grid class:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Grid extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }


    render(){
        let columns = [];
        let rows = [];
        if(this.props.data != null){
            columns = this.props.data.slice(0, 1).map((row, i) => {
                return(
                  Object.keys(row).map((column, key) => {
                    return(
                      <th key={key}>{column}</th>
                    )
                  })
                )
                })

            rows = this.props.data.map((row, rowKey) => {
              return(
                  <tr key={rowKey}>
                {Object.keys(row).map((data, cellKey) => {
                  return(
                  <td key={cellKey} suppressContentEditableWarning="true" contentEditable="true" onChange={this.props.onInput(rowKey)}>{row[data]}</td>
                  )
                })}
              </tr>
              )
            })
        }
        return(
            <table>
            <thead><tr>{columns}</tr></thead>
            <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
          </table>
        )
    }
}

export default Grid;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when your component is rendered any time, you are calling your `onInput`method:

```
<td 
    key={cellKey} 
    suppressContentEditableWarning="true" 
    contentEditable="true" 
--> onChange={this.props.onInput(rowKey)}>{row[data]}</td>
```

Instead of calling it you have to pass the a function, in this case you can pass an `anonymous function` or an `arrow function`:

```
<td  
    key={cellKey} 
    suppressContentEditableWarning="true" 
    contentEditable="true" 
--> onChange={ () => { this.props.onInput(rowKey); } }>{row[data]}</td>
```